# Is it necessary to use Thread.Sleep(1) in a while loop on iOS and Android when I make an asynchronous call?

Tags: c#, android, ios

Is it necessary to use Thread.Sleep(1) in a while loop when I make asynchronous calls? Or can I just use my while loop without the line Thread.Sleep(1):

```
 while (_running == true)
 {

 }
```

Does it make a difference if I use Thread.Sleep(1) in an iOS or Android phone game? Is it possible that my game crashes if I don't use Thread.Sleep(1)?

My code:

```
  private static bool _running = false;
  bool loggedin = false;
  string PlayerDeviceId = "";
  string PlayerPlayFabID = "";

  private void RegisterGuestPlayFabAccount()
  {
      PlayerDeviceId = ReturnMobileID();
      var requestIOS = new LoginWithIOSDeviceIDRequest { DeviceId = PlayerDeviceId, CreateAccount = true };
      var loginTask = PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithIOSDeviceIDAsync(requestIOS);
      loginTask.ContinueWith(OnPlayFabRegisterGuestAccountComplete);
  }

  private void OnPlayFabRegisterGuestAccountComplete(Task<PlayFabResult<LoginResult>> task)
  {
      if (task.Result.Result != null)
      {
          _running = true;
          GetPlayFabAccountInfo();
          while (_running == true)
          {
              Thread.Sleep(1);
          }

          loggedin = true;
      }

      if (task.Result.Error != null)
      {
          OnPlayFabError(task.Result.Error);
      }
  }

  private void GetPlayFabAccountInfo()
  {
      var request = new GetAccountInfoRequest { };
      var loginTask = PlayFabClientAPI.GetAccountInfoAsync(request);
      loginTask.ContinueWith(OnGetPlayFabAccountInfoComplete);
  }

  private void OnGetPlayFabAccountInfoComplete(Task<PlayFabResult<GetAccountInfoResult>> task)
  {
      if (task.Result.Result != null)
      {
          PlayerPlayFabID = task.Result.Result.AccountInfo.PlayFabId;
      }

      if (task.Result.Error != null)
      {
          OnPlayFabError(task.Result.Error);
      }

      _running = false;
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use ContinueWith in OnPlayFabRegisterGuestAccountComplete instead of busy-waiting it?

Comment: Both of your solutions would waste of lot of CPU busy-waiting for the async operation to complete, and I would consider both to be very bad solutions to this problem. The real problem is that you don't know how to use asyncronous programming in C# (yet).
You should read up on using the `async`/`await` keywords, or at least understand why your suggested solution is bad. You could use ContinueWith better, and avoid the busy-wait loop

Comment: How should I use ContinueWith in my code? I don't know how to use ContinueWith in OnPlayFabRegisterGuestAccountComplete. Is ContinueWith always better than a while loop if I need to await an operation to complete?

Comment: Just call `var task = PlayFabClientAPI.GetAccountInfoAsync()` instead of `GetPlayFabAccountInfo();`.
Then you set `loggedin = true;` in the function you provide to `ContinueWith`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking if you're using any kind of sleep in your code there's probably a better way to do it.

For any operations that are potentially long running you should put them in an async task and deal with them in the foreground on completion. Indeed in android you have to do network operations on a background task otherwise an exception is thrown.